# Why doesn't my UI properly rerender my deleted object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I have a parent component that maps over a `list` state using an `Input` component

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Input from "./Input";

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([{}]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("list", list);
  }, [list]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {list.map((_, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <Input id={i} setList={setList} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Submitting each `Input` leaves another `Input` available for submission. However, when I delete each `Input`, I see that the data object is gone but the UI doesn't reflect this.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Input = ({ setList, id }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const result = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    setValue(result);
  };
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setList((list) => [...list, { id: id, total: value }]);
    setSubmitted(true);
  };
  const handleDelete = () => {
    console.log("id", id);
    setList((list) => list.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={new Intl.NumberFormat("ko-KR", {
          style: "currency",
          currency: "KRW"
        }).format(Number(value))}
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
      />
      {submitted ? (
        <button disabled={value.length === 0} onClick={handleDelete}>
          Delete
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button disabled={value.length === 0} onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Submit!
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

I suspect that this is because

```
  const [list, setList] = useState([{}])
```

Is initialized with an empty object, and that is causing the problem. However, I need at least one object inside the `list` state so I can have the initial `Input` component for submission.

How do I properly delete my `Input` component?

My [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-7qho5q?file=/src/App.js:0-500)

Comment: Add `setSubmitted(false);` in `handleDelete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because you used index as a key in map.

You can read more about it [here](https://dev.to/shiv1998/why-not-to-use-index-as-key-in-react-lists-practical-example-3e66).

Long story short, for example you have 3 items, you delete second that has key "2", then your third element receive a key "2" and react think that this is the same element.

I updated your example with item template that have temp id set to "new item" and used id as a key.

Also I create id for each new element in handleSubmit function, so your temp id never became a real one.

Here is updated code. I removed some code that wasn't changed.

App component

```
const TEMPLATE = {
  id: "new item",
  value: 0,
}

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([{...TEMPLATE}]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {list.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <Input id={item.id} setList={setList} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is Input component. You would want to generate Id in some other way.

```
const Input = ({ setList, id }) => {
  ...
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setList((list) => [...list, { id: Math.random(), total: value }]);
    setSubmitted(true);
  };
  ...    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with your `key`

```js
<div key={i}></div>
```

React uses the `key` prop to help identify what elements have been changed. Keys should remain the same for each element in your array across re-renders, so that React can identify when an element has been updated based on a state change. As you're removing elements from your state, the index doesn't serve as a stable key that is uniquely associated with your object (as objects shift into lower indexes when one is removed). Instead, it's best to add some sort of `id` associated with the elements that you render:

```js
const [list, setList] = useState([{ id: 0}]);
...
{list.map(({ id }) => (
  <div key={id}>
    <Input id={id} setList={setList} />
  </div>
))}
...
```

Then in your component where you add your objects, you can create a new `id` (which doesn't change) for each new object. Below I've used `Math.random()`, but you should use something more reliable than that (eg: [uuidv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4)).

```js
setList((list) => [...list, { id: Math.random(), total: value }]);
```

You should also look into how you're adding new values. The "submit" Input only appears because of the new object that you're adding to your list: `{ id: Math.random(), total: value }`. I would instead have `App` display one Input which is primarily responsible for adding items to your `list` state, and then have each `Input` that is rendered within the `.map()` take care of the "delete" functionality.